# Does NSCoding / NSKeyedArchiving data persist through a major iOS update?

Tags: ios, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver

Will the data persist through a major update, such as from iOS 10 to iOS 11? Any reason it might not?

Comment: If it didn't, millions of users would be screaming about lost data right now.

Comment: Clarify your question. Are you asking if data saved via archiving under iOS 10 can be unarchived under iOS 11? Or are you asking if a file saved under iOS 10 will still exist after a user updates to iOS 11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the data **will persist** after an update or a restore/backup as well. It only disappears from the device when the application gets deleted or you erase the app cache (it's possible on a jailbroken device or with iFunBox etc.)